# Problem with mount path using the volumes on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a 3 node cluster (1 master and 2 worker nodes)
I have a deployment running with pod image as **nginx** on one of workers node. The following is its manifest definition:-

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
          - name: logs
            mountPath: /var/log/nginx
```

If I tail the nginx logs, I can see logs are getting generated in the location as /var/log/nginx:-

```
vagrant@mykubemaster:~/my-k8s/sidecar$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-5bb7d5c6dd-hjxnr   1/1     Running   0          8m8s
vagrant@mykubemaster:~/my-k8s/sidecar$ kubectl exec nginx-5bb7d5c6dd-hjxnr -- tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
10.32.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2021:02:43:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.32.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2021:02:43:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.32.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2021:02:46:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.32.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2021:02:46:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
10.32.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2021:02:48:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "-"
```

However, the problem is if I ssh into the worker nodes (both) and even the master node, I do not see any folder as **nginx** created under /var/log then where this file (access.log) is getting stored which I can stream very well using the -f and --tail command?

My understanding was when we do a volume mount then Pod uses the VM's storage location where the pod got provisioned. If on node02, then at some location as specified in the manifest on Node02.

I would really appreciate if you can help me to understand on this and find the file path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're storing the logs in an [`emptyDir` volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).  That's not intended to be persistent, or to be accessed from outside the pod; it doesn't have a fixed location on the host system, and the content there will be lost as soon as the pod is deleted.

In the specific case of `image: nginx`, the Docker Hub `nginx` image is configured by default to write its access logs to the container's stdout.  If you delete the `volumes:` and `volumeMounts:`, then `kubectl logs deployment/nginx` will show you the access logs.  A cluster administrator can then deploy a log collector to forward these logs to somewhere else; see *e.g.* [Using a node logging agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-node-logging-agent) in the Kubernetes documentation.

This same advice can apply to most other processes: set logging to go to the process's standard output and not a file, and Kubernetes will collect it, and you can deploy a forwarder to send the logs somewhere else if you need to review them later.

Comment: thanks and really appreciated it. It is clear to me now :)